# Rollingout updates in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack, downtime

Created a micro service application with spring initializer and deployed using docker.

For rolling out the latest changes creating the docker image with the latest code changes

```
docker stack deploy -c stack.yml mystack
```

application is running with 2 replicas. Updating the services with docker service update.

```
docker service update --force service-name
```

Can anyone please help me with sample stack and best practice to deploy  for zero downtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can find nice text here 
https://blog.capstonec.com/2018/06/28/zero-downtime-deployment-with-docker-rolling-updates/

Below is an excerpt from the Docker reference documentation which can be found at:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config.

- parallelism: The number of containers to update at a time.
- delay: The time to wait between updating a group of containers.
- failure_action: What to do if an update fails. One of continue, rollback, or  pause (default: pause).
- monitor: Duration after each task update to monitor for failure (ns|us|ms|s|m|h) (default 0s).
- max_failure_ratio: Failure rate to tolerate during an update.
- order: Order of operations during updates. One of stop-first (old task is stopped before starting new one), or start-first(new task is started first, and the running tasks will briefly overlap) (default stop-first) Note: Only supported for v3.4 and higher.